# How can I pass my data between my classes on PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots

I made an joystick with qframe class and also  i converted my mouse location data to -1,1 but when i try to send this location data to my mainwindow class with pyqt signal it gives an error 'pyqt signal has no attiribute emit' like this, i go to pyqtSignal class
[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXtxA.png) it really dont have emit function but there are many example like this on the net,does my pyqt files broken or something or is it because of  absance of QObject class? How can i pass my data to other class?

**Here it is my joystick class;**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from PyQt5.QtCore import  QPointF, QTimer,  Qt ,pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFrame, QApplication, QLabel
import sys
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy

class clock(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(clock,self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(300,300)
        self.setMaximumSize(300,300)
        self.x=self.width()/2
        self.y=self.height()/2
        self.relative_x=0
        self.relative_y=0
        self.signal=pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def sub(self):
        self.node=rospy.init_node("hanınamk",anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber('/joy',Joy,self.joyControl)

    def joyControl(self,data):
        self.data=data.axes
        self.x=(-(self.data[0]*150)+150)
        self.y=(-(self.data[1]*150)+150)
        print(self.data[0],self.data[1])
        self.repaint()

    def paintEvent(self,event):
    
        pen=QPen()
        pen.setWidth(5)
        pen.setBrush(Qt.black)
        painter=QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.rect())
        
        painter_2=QPainter(self)
        painter_2.setBrush(Qt.black)
        painter_2.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter_2.drawEllipse(QPointF(self.x,self.y),50,50)

    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,e):
        self.relative_x=(e.x()-150)/150.0
        self.relative_y=(e.y()-150)/150.0  
        # print(round(self.relative_x,1),round(self.relative_y,1))
        self.signal.emit(self.relative_x)
        if self.relative_x**2+self.relative_y**2<1: 
            self.x=e.x()
            self.y=e.y()
            self.repaint()
    
    def mousePressEvent(self,e):
        if self.relative_x**2+self.relative_y**2<1:  
            self.x=e.x()
            self.y=e.y()
            self.repaint()

    def mousePressEvent(self,e):
        if self.relative_x**2+self.relative_y**2<1: 
            self.x=e.x()
            self.y=e.y()
            self.repaint()

    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,e):
        self.x=self.width()/2
        self.y=self.height()/2
        self.repaint()
    


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=clock()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**and my main class;**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget
import sys
from joystick import clock

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Main')
        self.setMinimumSize(900,900)
        self.setMaximumSize(900,900)
        layout=QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setGeometry(QRect(200,200,300,300))
        self.joy=clock()
        self.joy_2=clock()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.joy)
        layout.addWidget(self.joy_2)
        self.label=QLabel(self)
    
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_change(self,data):
        print(data)




if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Make the signal a class attribute. You need to connect the signal to your slot as well.

Comment: Can you explain detailed with some brief code please?

Comment: @montana57 See: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html Note: do not use the `sip` files as reference, they're not python scripts and are not intended to be used as base for documentation or implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Make the signal a class attribute not an instance attribute:

```
class clock(QFrame):
    signal = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
```

and connect it in `Main.__init__`:

```
self.joy.signal.connect(self.on_change)
self.joy2.signal.connect(self.on_change)
```